# xrdb -merge ~/.Xresources disables gtk anti-aliasing

Tags: fonts, xmonad, antialiasing

When booting into xmonad, gtk fonts are anti-aliased, but for some reason urxvt has problems with variable names in my `~/.Xresources` (it fails to parse the variable names as colors and thus everything is pink). This is fixed by running `xrdb -merge ~/.Xresources`. However, doing this seems to disable anti-aliasing for fonts in gtk apps, but *not* in urxvt.

What would be causing this?

My ~/.Xresources: http://paste.ubuntu.com/6560111/

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I am having the same issue.

Comment: The reason everything is pink is because you are using `#define` in your .Xresources. When `xrdb` is called at login it is run with `-nocpp` which causes it to throw an error when parsing `#define`. There's a solution here (posts #6 and #7) where the file is run through the pre-processor manually before being passed to `xrdb`.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1163129

Comment: Personally I ended up just adding a manual `xrdb -merge /home/alecb/.Xdefaults` to my `xmonad.hs`